# Video no longer appearing in video editor?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, video

I am new to blender and animation in general.
I poured hours into one simple 2d animation. i had a basic version that saved and worked.
I came back and made some visual improvments and added sounds. but now there is no image appearing in the video editor and whenever i try to render it sticks at zero frames and shows a black screen.. (i can still load the file and play it perfectly with sounds and everything, the problem comes as soon as i try to render again.)

what am i doing wrong?? ive been trying to fix it for so long!

Edit: I can render the animation but all frames are black

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/40164/2843, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/40411/2843

Comment: Duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44720/2843