# Move video clips in one place

Tags: video-sequence-editor, blend-files

I just finished editing a video, and I realized that some video clip files used are still in the client's USB flash drive :( Is there a way (like a python script) to tell Blender "gather all the material used in this .blend file in this directory"?

How can I give him his drive back, without risking coming back to this .blend file later to find files missing?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41750/2843

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close Blender. Copy the files to your local hard drive. Unplug the USB drive. Open your file in Blender. Hit File -> External Data -> Find missing files. Select folder containing local files. Hit Find missing files.

Comment: Perfick. I had just found it out thanks to Samoth's link, but you basically nailed it.